# Java Import data from CSV into SQL prevent double entry

Tags: java, sql, csv

I have the following codes. I am not sure how do I arrange them such that it can check for entry in the CSV before adding the record into the SQL database.
Problem is I am still adding double record into the sql

```
try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String[] data1 = br.readLine().split(cvsSplitBy);

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String queryCheck = "SELECT Count(Name) from DB WHERE Name = ?";

            PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(queryCheck);
            //value is the data of the name column in the CSV
            st.setString(1, data1[0]);
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
            boolean recordFound = rs.next();

            if (recordFound) {
                //dont add record

                System.out.println("found " + data1[0]);

            } else {


                String[] data = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

                String sql2 = "INSERT INTO DB (Name, ID, Age) values (?, ?, ?)";
                pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
                pstmt.setString(1, data[0]);
                pstmt.setString(2, data[1]);
                pstmt.setString(3, data[2]);
                pstmt.executeUpdate();
            }

        }
```

Comment: put your `while` loop inside `else`

Comment: still adding double record even if i do it

Comment: are you sure that you are comparing the correct value of `name`? how did you retrieve the value of `value` from csv?

Comment: ok now there is another problem..when a record is found, it will skip the check of rest of the entry. hence everything after a found is not added

Comment: Add the rest of your try/catch block... are any exceptions thrown. Also can you update the code to what you have now?

Comment: i think the problem lies with the value, i change it to data1[0] so that it better get the record in the csv, but problem is now its keep detecting the first entry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code above only check for the existence of the first row data in your database.
put your *query check* inside `while` loop as well.

And you should simply `SELECT *` Instead of `SELECT count(Name)` because `SELECT count(Name)` will give you result even if the count result is `0`

Try this:

```
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String queryCheck, insert;
    PreparedStatement st;
    ResultSet rs;
    boolean recordFound;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        queryCheck = "SELECT * from DB WHERE Name = ?";
        String[] data1 = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
        System.out.println("Name= " + data1[0] + " , ID= " + data1[1] + " , Age= " + data1[2]);
        st = conn.prepareStatement(queryCheck);
        st.setString(1, data1[0]);
        rs = st.getResultSet();
        recordFound = rs.next();

        if (recordFound) {
            System.out.println(data1[0]+" already exist in the database!");
        }
        else{
            String[] data = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            insert = "INSERT INTO DB (Name, ID, Age) values (?, ?, ?)";
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(insert);
            pstmt.setString(1, data[0]);
            pstmt.setString(2, data[1]);
            pstmt.setString(3, data[2]);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Probably want to move some of the variable declarations outside the while loop , `String queryCheck`, `String[] data1`, `PreparedStatement st` etc so you're not redeclaring them each iteration.

Comment: wow.i am getting a little confuse here..i need time to look at this now

Comment: @ninabei take your time :)

Comment: @Rafa El thanks for the help, finally I understand the code =D

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a couple a little mis-steps in logic. You need to use your if statement to control when the insert is called. I inverted your `recordFound` variable because if the record is found you just want to do nothing, thus no need for the else block. Looks like this:

```
     if (!recordFound) {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                 String[] data = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

                 String sql2 = "INSERT INTO DB (Name, ID, Age) values (?, ?, ?)";
                 pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
                 pstmt.setString(1, data[0]);
                 pstmt.setString(2, data[1]);
                 pstmt.setString(3, data[2]);
                 pstmt.executeUpdate();
           }
     }
```

Also I believe you're misusing the `rs.next()` call as well; even if the count is 0 that value is still being returned and it will always result in the `rs.next()` call being true . You need to get the value of the result and see if it's greater than 0. Something like this:

```
boolean recordFound = false;
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(queryCheck);
//value is the data of the name column in the CSV
st.setString(1, value);
ResultSet rs = st.getResultSet();
rs.first();//move cursor to single result
if(rs.getInt(1) > 0)
    recordFound = true;
```

Also you are reading the first line of your file in a static fashion and then later in the `found` block are trying to then loop over it. You need to just loop over it initially instead of looking at the first line and then looping afterwards